# Working with triggers, cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I'm using SQL server 2012 and have got a db already created in which I have four main tables which are linked through a view that triggers one trigger and leads from one table to another. Trigers work to move the needed info from one table to another.

As you may imagine, the main issue has to do with the amount of triggers that db generates and in the end, there is a pop-up window which shows a time-out warning related to the db. What could be the solution for this?

I've thought of creating a block which contains a cursor and within it, another cursor instead of creating a loop of triggers. How could I do that about cursors in the db, what's the correct sintax?

Is there any idea better than that one? I havent tried that one as I dont know how to do so and maybe I continue having the same issue related to "time-out" but I do not have any other idea and wanted to give it a try.

Comment: Impossible to say what is causing problems, but I would not start using cursors.

Comment: There's far too little information here for anybody to be able to troubleshoot your issue. In general, triggers have some overhead associated with them, of course, but your issue is probably related to doing something inefficiently in the triggers, possibly due to missing, suitable indexes.

Comment: its better if you share the data structure with sample code (triggers)

Comment: post your trigger code please

Comment: This would be one example in one table:USE [Table_name]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================

-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ExplosionExpedientes_TipoTrabajo_EXEC]
   ON  [dbo].[Proyeccion_Mes]